# How can I construct a new Set basing on some condition?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I was trying to learn the basics of scala and was dealing with set operation. I havent been able to find much data regarding the reading of scala set iteratively and creating new sets.

The basic task I am doing is to iterate over the contents of Set and select a few values that meets the conditions and make a new set out of them.

So the idea basically is like this

```
for all elements in Set
    if (condition) add element to set
    else discard element
```

Any help with the syntax for such a statement would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set.filter (condition)
```

should return a new set of elements, satisfying the condition.

It's the same syntax as for

```
vector.filter (condition)
array.filter (condition)
map.filter (condition)
list.filter (condition)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` method on `Set` for that. For example, if you have `set: Set[Int]` and you want to filter all even numbers, you'd do something like

```
set.filter(x => x % 2 == 0)
```